# MassTransit consumers disconnecting from RabbitMQ when multiple queues used in single application

Tags: .net, rabbitmq, masstransit

We have an app using MassTransit with RabbitMQ transport that has multiple queues and multiple connections to RabbitMQ. We're seeing that, as we add more queues (which, by default, adds more connections), the app will start, *some* consumers will connect but then disconnect after a minute or two, and other consumers never seem to connect. We have found that this seems to be affected by the CPU core count of the host running the app and the prefetch count so, for the time being we have scaled up the host and dropped the prefetch count, but this is not ideal.

The receive endpoints are configured using something similar to:

```
Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(sbc => 
{
   sbc.ReceiveEndpoint("some-queue", endpoint => 
   {
      endpoint.Consumer(() => scope.Resolve<SomeConsumerType>());
   });
   // repeat for other queues
});
```

What I would like to know is:

- Is this behaviour controlled by some sort of timeout in registering consumers and, if so, can we increase this timeout?
- Is there a way to specify that receive endpoints re-use existing connections so that we can have multiple queues hanging off the same connection (ie, similar to RabbitMQ's connection and channel models)?

Comment: What version of MassTransit? The configuration syntax seems really outdated. Any issues related to the broker connection are always logged, so check the logs.

Comment: @ChrisPatterson it's version 8.0.7, but most likely it was originally written when the app was referencing a much earlier version.

Comment: Well, same answer, logs.